# How can I do a covering design parameter search using SageMath?

Tags: sage

I am trying to find all non-isomorphic covering designs of C(12,6,3)=15 where v=12, k=6 and t=3.

Is SageMath capable of doing parameter searches?

So far I have generated this code using chatgpt, however I keep running into errors:

```
    from sage.combinat.designs.covering_design import CoveringDesign

# Define the parameters of the covering design
v = 7  # number of points
k = 4  # block size
t = 2  # number of blocks containing any given point

# Generate all covering designs with those parameters
cover_designs = list(CoveringDesign(v, k, t))

# Filter out non-isomorphic designs
non_iso_designs = []
for design in cover_designs:
    is_iso = False
    for non_iso in non_iso_designs:
        if is_isomorphic(design, non_iso):
            is_iso = True
            break
    if not is_iso:
        non_iso_designs.append(design)

# Print the non-isomorphic designs
for d in non_iso_designs:
    print(d)
```

Is there another approach to finding non-isomorphic covering designs? Also, what is the fastest software out there that can do these parameter searches?

Thanks in advance!
Justin.

Answer (score 0):

C(12,6,3) = 15
Method of Construction: lex covering
Lower Bound: Handbook of Combinatorial Designs section on coverings
1  2  3  4  5  6
1  2  7  8  9 10
3  4  7  8 11 12
5  6  9 10 11 12
1  2  3  9 11 12
1  4  5  7 10 11
2  4  6  8 10 12
3  5  6  7  8  9
1  3  6  7 10 12
1  4  5  8  9 12
2  3  5  8 10 11
2  4  6  7  9 11
1  3  6  8  9 11
2  3  5  7  9 12
1  2  3  4  9 10

Comment: Hello Roberto, yes this is one non-isomorphic covering design for c(12,6,3) as found on La Jolla Covering Repository. I was wondering if there is a program that is free to use which can find all (or most) non-isomorphic covering designs. I know that “nauty” is one program that is used but I was wondering if there are others. Specifically I would like to know how long it takes “nauty” to find all non-isomorphic covering designs for c(12,6,3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).